# Angular2 - Component based architecture

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui, angular2-components

Custom property is used for data binding across components.

```
          <section id="main">
              <app-home [dict]="dict">Hello there!</app-home>
          </section>
```

here, `dict` is a custom property, where `app-home` is selector of one component used in other component.

---

The idea of components in Angular2 is to be *highly cohesive* and *loosely coupled*.

---

Why angular2 allow data binding across components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing data from parent to child with input binding is main 
approach for component interaction.In summary this is required by development.

Comment: Child component  should be loosely coupled for re-usability.

Comment: any component may have ineraction with outside.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `<section>` is parent component and `<app-home>` is child component.

Now in Angular 2 there is no such thing like `$rootScope`, but sharing data between components is important.

Now there are options available for data sharing between components.
Eg. **Shared Services**, and **Parent-Child** relation.

In Parent Child component data sharing we use @Input and @Output.

The example you shared is **parent to child** data sharing.

`[propertyName]="sharedValue"` this is the main approach used for **Parent to Child** component data sharing.

Comment: Read hayden's answer

Comment: I did. Thought I'd elaborate a little.

Comment: You are talking about the mechanics to use data binding.